# Error:- tensorboard: command not found . However, while typing locate tensorboard, I am getting the the location

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am a beginner in tensorflow. I ran a simple script as below :

```
import tensorflow as tf

a =tf.constant(2)
b  = tf.constant(3)
c = tf.add(a,b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs',sess.graph)
    print sess.run(c)

writer.close()
```

After saving this python file, I ran it in terminal. There is folder graphs created with 2 events file. Then I ran following command on terminal :

```
tensorboard --logdir="./graphs"
```

I am getting following error:

```
tensorboard: command not found
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.
​

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are getting `tensorboard` location, try to run your command with your local path, ex

```
/your/path/tensorboard --logdir="./graphs"
```

Hope this will help you, happy coding